# how to let the user check/mark dates as finished

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Hey guys I'm trying to find a way to let the user check/mark off their dates. I got an index view that lists dates. I want the user to be able to mark dates as finished the opportunity to unmark.

I created a table `marked_dates`, which references the `user.id` and the `dates.id`

Thanks for advise

Comment: Can you show us some code? You model, controller, view? And explain where you're stuck? What doesn't work? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, assuming the simplest case possible.
Add a new boolean field to your model: generate new migration, something like

```
class AddColumnToMarkedDates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :marked_dates, :marked, :boolean
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :marked_dates, :marked, :boolean
  end
end
```

Then modify index view. Simplest way to display the state of date would be `<%=marked_date.marked%>`, which of course will show you true or false.